# Hydra - Override parameters when instantiating function

Tags: python, fb-hydra

I am working on a data pipeline that follows a structure like this:

```
-- src/
---- etl.py
---- scripts/
------ moduleA.py
------ moduleB.py
```

I want to parametrise the scripts with Hydra. I have already done it for moduleA, which can be run independently:

```py
import os

import hydra
from omegaconf import DictConfig

@hydra.main(config_path=os.getcwd(), config_name="config")
def main(cfg: DictConfig) -> None:

    # Parse args
    input_file: str = cfg.params.input_file

    do_stuff(input_file)
```

I would like to have the same approach for moduleB et al **and** being able to to instantiate these `main()` from `etl.py`, which will act as the orchestrator.

TLDR: Is it possible to parametrise a function that reads from a config file without having to renounce to use Hydra? I would like `etl.py` to be something like this:

```py
import os

import hydra
from omegaconf import DictConfig

from scripts.moduleA import main as process_moduleA

@hydra.main(config_path=os.getcwd(), config_name="config")
def main(cfg: DictConfig) -> None:

    # Parse args
    input_file: str = cfg.params.input_file

    process_moduleA(input_file)
```

Many thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

The typical pattern is to use an `if __name__ == "__main__"` guard in your `moduleA.py` and `moduleB.py` files:

```py
# moduleA.py
import hydra
from omegaconf import DictConfig

@hydra.main(config_path=os.getcwd(), config_name="config")
def main(cfg: DictConfig) -> None:
   ...

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

This way, when you call `moduleA` from your `etl.py` script, the Hydra machinery in `moduleA.py` will not be triggered.